# How to generate predictions from new data using trained tensorflow network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to train Googles [VGGish](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset/vggish) network ([Hershey et al 2017](http://10.1109/ICASSP.2017.7952132)) from scratch to predict classes specific to my own audio files.

For this I am using the [vggish_train_demo.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/audioset/vggish/vggish_train_demo.py) script available on their github repo which uses tensorflow. I've been able to modify the script to extract melspec features from my own audio by changing the `_get_examples_batch()` function, and, then train the model on the output of this function. This runs to completetion and prints the loss at each epoch.

However, I've been unable to figure out how to get this trained model to generate predictions from new data. Can this be done with changes to the vggish_train_demo.py script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this in the future, I wrote this script which does the job. You must save logmel specs for train and test data in the arrays: X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test. The X_train/test are arrays of the (n, 96,64) features and the y_train/test are arrays of shape (n, _NUM_CLASSES) for two classes, where n = the number of 0.96s audio segments and _NUM_CLASSES = the number of classes used.

See the function definition statement for more info and the vggish github in my original post:

```
### Run the network and save the predictions and accuracy at each epoch

### Train NN, output results
r"""This uses the VGGish model definition within a larger model which adds two 
layers on top, and then trains this larger model. 

We input log-mel spectrograms (X_train) calculated above with associated labels 
(y_train), and feed the batches into the model. Once the model is trained, it 
is then executed on the test log-mel spectrograms (X_test), and the accuracy is
ouput, alongside a .csv file with the predictions for each 0.96s chunk and their
true class."""
    
def main(X):   
  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Define VGGish.
    embeddings = vggish_slim.define_vggish_slim(training=FLAGS.train_vggish)
    
    
    # Define a shallow classification model and associated training ops on top
    # of VGGish.
    with tf.variable_scope('mymodel'):
      # Add a fully connected layer with 100 units. Add an activation function
      # to the embeddings since they are pre-activation.
      num_units = 100
      fc = slim.fully_connected(tf.nn.relu(embeddings), num_units)

      # Add a classifier layer at the end, consisting of parallel logistic
      # classifiers, one per class. This allows for multi-class tasks.
      logits = slim.fully_connected(                                 
          fc, _NUM_CLASSES, activation_fn=None, scope='logits')
      tf.sigmoid(logits, name='prediction')
    
      linear_out= slim.fully_connected(                                      
          fc, _NUM_CLASSES, activation_fn=None, scope='linear_out')
      logits = tf.sigmoid(linear_out, name='logits')
    
      # Add training ops.
      with tf.variable_scope('train'):
        global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()

        # Labels are assumed to be fed as a batch multi-hot vectors, with
        # a 1 in the position of each positive class label, and 0 elsewhere.
        labels_input = tf.placeholder(
            tf.float32, shape=(None, _NUM_CLASSES), name='labels')

        # Cross-entropy label loss.
        xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=labels_input, name='xent')  
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent, name='loss_op')
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

        # We use the same optimizer and hyperparameters as used to train VGGish.
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            learning_rate=vggish_params.LEARNING_RATE,
            epsilon=vggish_params.ADAM_EPSILON)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    # Initialize all variables in the model, and then load the pre-trained
    # VGGish checkpoint.
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())         
    vggish_slim.load_vggish_slim_checkpoint(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint)

    # The training loop.
    features_input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(
        vggish_params.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME)
    


    accuracy_scores = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):#FLAGS.num_batches):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i=0
            while i < len(X_train):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(X_train[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(y_train[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={features_input: batch_x, labels_input: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+=batch_size
            #print no. of epochs and loss
            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of', num_epochs,', loss:',epoch_loss) #FLAGS.num_batches,', loss:',epoch_loss)
            
            #If these lines are left here, it will evaluate on the test data every iteration and print accuracy
            #note this adds a small computational cost
            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels_input, 1)) #This line returns the max value of each array, which we want to be the same (think the prediction/logits is value given to each class with the highest value being the best match)
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float')) #changes correct to type: float
            accuracy1 = accuracy.eval({features_input:X_test, labels_input:y_test}) 
            accuracy_scores.append(accuracy1)
            print('Accuracy:', accuracy1)#TF is smart so just knows to feed it through the model without us seeming to tell it to.



            #Save predictions for test data
            predictions_sigm = logits.eval(feed_dict = {features_input:X_test}) #not really _sigm, change back later
            #print(predictions_sigm) #shows table of predictions, meaningless if saving at each epoch
            test_preds = pd.DataFrame(predictions_sigm, columns = col_names)  #converts predictions to df
            true_class = np.argmax(y_test, axis = 1)     #This saves the true class
            test_preds['True class'] = true_class        #This adds true class to the df
        
            #Saves csv file of table of predictions for test data. NB. header will not save when using np.text for some reason
           np.savetxt("/content/drive/MyDrive/..."+"Epoch_"+str(epoch+1)+"_Accuracy_"+str(accuracy1), test_preds.values, delimiter=",") 

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()


#'An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.' error will occur, fear not, this just means its finished (perhaps as its exited the tensorflow session?)
```